# add watch shows undefined identifier visual studio 2012, cpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio, watch

I encounter the strangest behavior in VS 2012 (I'm writing in cpp).

I click "add watch" on a variable and it says "identifier  is undefined".

Here's an example of the code:

```
for (int j=0;j<32;j++)
        {
            unsigned char curValue=desc1.at<unsigned char>(0,j);
            printf("%s\n",curValue);    
        }
```

I had to use printf to show the value of curValue. lol.

Has anyone encountered such behavior?

Edit: more strange this occur. When debugging the following code:

```
    int b1[8];

    for (int k=0;k<7;k++)
        b1[k]=0;

    char q=curValue; 
    int t=0;
    while (q!=0){
        b1[t++]=q%2;
        q=q/2;
    }
```

The debugger just skips the loop with b1[k]=0;

Please note curValue is undefined even inside the loop.

Thanks!

Comment: Another Solution to the problem is to leave optimizations of the compiler enabled, but enable /Zo (Enhance Optimized Debugging) telling the compiler to generate additional debugging information that work with the optimized code. This is only available for Visual Studio 2013 update 3 or later. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn785163.aspx

Comment: This problem has been around for YEARS over many versions of VS.  Another example of the half-assed implementation of C++ by Microsoft.  (You never see nonsense like this with C#.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As Joachim said: curValue is defined inside the loop. If watch window in visual studio see it as undefined value then you should turn off Compiler optimization.

Compiler optimization default is /O2 optimize for speed. To turn it off :

- Go to project, right click and choose  properties
- Configuration Properties->C/C++->Optimization
- select optimization , and change it from Maximize Speed (/O2) to Disabled (/Od)
  [image]

Comment: Notice also that this is mainly used for a debug configuration mode, not suitable to releases which should be both bug-free and optimized.
Thank you.

Comment: in vs 2019 optimization is off but variable is still undefined.

Answer (score 4):

I had optimizations turned on. That messed up my debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Without the printf, the first loop has no side effects and is thus likely optimized away in an optimized build.  In the second example, the loop that initializes the small array to 0 is probably replaced with an initialized data section.

You should probably try to debug with an unoptimized build.

Also note that the Visual Studio debugger has pretty good visualizers for the standard containers.  So if the whole point of the first loop was just to peek at the contents of `desc1`, you can probably just examine it directly in the debugger.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the variable `curValue` is only valid inside the loop, if you try to add it to the watch when you're not in the loop then the variable is not defined.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's undefined even inside the loop.

Comment: @user2215359 Have you optimizations turned on? They can mess things up when debugging. And in this case, if the loop doesn't contain more than the assignment to `curValue` most likely *will* be optimized away.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How to I check if I have optimizations turned on?

Answer (score 1):

Because `curValue` gets out of scope outside the `for` loop.

Also note that you should use `%c` in `printf` to print `char`. `%s` is used for C-style strings.

```
printf("%c\n",curValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable `curValue` is only valid inside the loop. If you will try to add it to the "watch" when you aren't in the loop, then your variable will be not defined.

Note: Better you should print this:

```
printf("%c\n",curValue);
```

Instead of this:

```
printf("%s\n",curValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Restart Visual Studio. Worked for me.